# xcode iOS check url prefix every time

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am at start in Xcode , i need a short script which verifies my url prefix

in php it would be something like this

```
<?php
    $prefix1 = "loc:";
    if (Webview == $prefix1)
    {
        echo "Url Prefix is loc:";
    }
?>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSURL *url = ...;
if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"loc"]) {
    NSLog(@"Url Prefix is loc:");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function available in [NSString class - hasPrefix method](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/hasPrefix:)

```
if ([myString hasPrefix:@"http"])
```

The other way is available in [NSURL class - Scheme property](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-BAJBIGDJ)

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
```

Then

```
url.scheme means, http
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I do not recommend using hasPrefix if you can use NSURL. It's too easy to fall for false positives. E.g. the usual scammer trick of a URL like "http:⁄⁄www.google.com.really.a.username@scammerserver.com⁄" will match hasPrefix: @"http:⁄⁄www.google.com" while NSURL will extract the actual server name "scammerserver.com" when you request url.host

Answer (score 0):

If you are 100% sure you have a valid URL, use

```
NSURL* myURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://example.com"];
if( [myURL.scheme isEqualToString: @"http"] )
{
    // do something here.
}
```

If this URL is entered by the user, use `NSURLComponents` instead, which will cope better with partial or invalid URLs, and give less surprising results with that kind of data.